# Browser tab keeps loading after express js get method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to build a simple REST API using Express.js, first time using it.

So I run the Express application generator using `npx express-generator`. Then, on /routes/users.js, I add a get method to retrieve data from an MSSQL database with the following code:

```
router.get('/api/v1/test', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            let pool = await sql.connect(dbConfig);
            let result1 = await pool.request().query('select * from andromedadb.dbo.test');
            console.dir(result1);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err', err);
        }
    })();
});
```

I know the connection is successful because the console prints the following:

```
{
  recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [ { id: 1, name: 'hello', age: 17 } ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 1 ]
}
```

My issue is that the browser tab keeps loading and executing the get method over and over.

I also tried the code snippet on https://www.js-tutorials.com/nodejs-tutorial/simple-example-of-nodejs-express-with-mssql/#Listing_Nodejs_MSSQL_Using_Express, but the very same thing was happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send back some response with your `res` object or call the `next()` function to go into your next middleware, otherwise you are just leaving your request hanging, thus the infinite load. Add a `res.send()` or `res.json()` function to mark the end of your function.

```
router.get('/api/v1/test', (req, res) => {
(async () => {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(dbConfig);
        let result1 = await pool.request().query('select * from andromedadb.dbo.test');
        console.dir(result1);
res.status(200).send("Received the response successfully");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
    }
})();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to send the response back to the request. I just modified your code, Look at the changes in the below code.

```
router.get('/api/v1/test', (req, res) => {
(async () => {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(dbConfig);
        let result1 = await pool.request().query('select * from andromedadb.dbo.test');
        console.dir(result1);
        res.status(200).send(result1);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).send(err);
        console.log('err', err);
    }
})();
});
```

Comment: @AlejandroValladares Great 

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the route from the front end application?

As you are using an async function for your get method, remember to use 'await':

```
const response = await getRecordSet();

// do stuff with 'response'
```